# run leap motion in background on osx c++

Tags: c++, macos, motion-detection

since SDK Version 0.8 my app does not run in background anymore.
has someone an idea?

```
class LeapController :public Leap::Listener
{
    //...

    void onInit(const Leap::Controller& controller) 
    {
        std::cout << "Initialized" << std::endl;
        // here i set the app to run in background:
        controller.setPolicyFlags(Leap::Controller::POLICY_BACKGROUND_FRAMES);
    }
    //...

};
```

Comment: The code above works fine for me (on OS X). Is another Leap app running in the foreground?

Comment: Maybe the Qt Framework was the problem.